# Equivalent to (.*) in negative look behind assertion Regex Python

Tags: python, regex, negative-lookbehind

I am writing a negative lookbehind assertion expression in Python which performs the following function to parse a plain text file:

Does not match anything followed after http://**********************   ; but will match the pattern when it is not inside a http://*** link

```
Example:
http://www.test.com/aa4   cd6
bx2 vq9 
yu9 http://www.bh9.com/cj3

Matches: cd6,bx2,vq9 and yu9
```

So I tried regexps like

```
r'(?<!http://(.*))([a-z][a-z][0-9])'
r'(?<!http://*)([a-z][a-z][0-9])'
```

They did not work.

How to add .* or do similar opearion inside negative look behind assertion regex in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem: Lookbehind does not allow pattern whose length is not fixed.

Quick hack: Perhaps the following regexp does the job?

```
r'(?<![./])[a-z][a-z][0-9]'
```

It works like this:

```
>>> str = """http://www.test.com/aa4
... bx2 vq9 
... http://www.bh9.com/cj3
... """
>>> re.findall(r'(?<![./])[a-z][a-z][0-9]',str)
['bx2', 'vq9']
```

Or - as another solution - use a regexp matching urls to cut off all urls in your string and then search for `r'[a-z][a-z][0-9]'`

Comment: How does [./] perform the functionality?

Comment: @thinkcool: `[./]` matches a dot or a slash. I.e. the regexp presented in my answer matches all words `[a-z][a-z][0-9]` which do not follow a dot or a slash.

Comment: what happens when the pattern just follows a [.] or [./] It will not match .fd3 . Is there any foolproof solution?

Comment: I am not able to understand your newly edited answer. Can you tell me how to proceed with this?

Answer (score 1):

That not possible. Python allows only fixed length lookbehinds. That means no quantifier inside the lookbehind.

See here the feature list on [egular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html)